# Connecting to an HTTPS connection from Java

Tags: java, url, https, weblogic, httpsurlconnection

I want to connect to an https url `https://www.ovh.com/cgi-bin/sms/http2sms.cgi`, I used the following code:

```
URL ovhUrl = new URL("https://www.ovh.com/cgi-bin/sms/http2sms.cgi");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)ovhUrl.openConnection(); // error here

String s_getBody = String.format("account=%s&login=%s&password=%s&from=%s&to=%s&message=%s",
                                 URLEncoder.encode(account, "UTF-8"),
                                 URLEncoder.encode(login, "UTF-8"),
                                 URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"),
                                 URLEncoder.encode(from, "UTF-8"),
                                 URLEncoder.encode(to, "UTF-8"),
                                 URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8"));
```

However, everytime I execute it, I get an exception at the second line: 
`weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

I am using Weblogic Server, I found a solution here which is to add to the classpath, but I'd rather not change the classpath of my application or fiddling with Weblogic Server. Is there a another way to solve it, maybe by using another class or another method to be able to execute the https url?

Comment: What type is `URL` exactly?  Weblogic or java?

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't cast to `HttpsURLConnection`. Use

```
URLConnection connection = ovhUrl.openConnection();
```

Comment: But the url I'm using is an https url, and I tried using the `URLConnection`, and I go the following error: `FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.`

Comment: That's not the problem of your `xxxConnection` variable declaration. You still become an instance of `SOAPHttpsURLConnection`, but your are not casting it to a wrong class. The problem you have is that the SSL certificate your client receives from the Server is "unusable or corrupt". BTW, the error you see is a good hint that a HTTPS Connection is used (it tries to check the server identity but fails).

Comment: I was able to solve the `FATAL Alert` by checking the `JSSE SSL` option in the SSL tab of servers in Weblogic. It seems I can't do it unless I do something with Weblogic. http://oraclefuzion.blogspot.com/2014/07/fatal-alert-badcertificate-corrupt-or.html

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and setting handler to URL constructor helped me.

```
    URL url = new URL(null, "https://www.ovh.com/cgi-bin/sms/http2sms.cgi", new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
```